# Specific cloaking for legal reasons, better solution?

Tags: seo, country, cloaking

I have a somewhat specific question about Cloaking, I'm aware that this might be one of the worst things to do for SEO, however my client has a product that is due to legal reasons named differently in Germany, now this means based on the location of the visitor we have to change that name, therefore it has nothing to do with SEO at that point and we'd replace just the product name. Does anyone know if this affects SEO or knows about a technique to avoid this but still achieve our goal?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you serve the same content to users as you would to search engines, then it is not cloaking. eg - for german IP addresses/users, they get xx, and any german search bots would too. Google mainly crawls from usa.